# upgrade and move elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have a 1.7 elastic search server installed on single instance, I want to upgrade to move the data to another server with 2.4 cluster installed. Is this possible and how can I do this? the servers use Ubuntu linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Elastic's [guide](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration) regarding upgrading from 1.x to 2.x.

There is also an [migration tool](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration) provided by Elastic that can check your environment and data and let you know if you need to make any changes before you can upgrade & migrate.